# Javascript UDF Filter function fails with NullPointerException on Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, user-defined-functions

I'm currently using the MongoDBtoBigquery (Batch) template to transfer data from MongoDB to BigQuery. However, I encounter a NullPointerException every time I use a User-Defined Function (UDF) to filter the records. Interestingly, the template works fine when I don't define a UDF.

Even though the source data contains optional fields, the field I'm trying to filter on is always present. I'm guessing that the template requires all rows to be returned and none can be skipped. But if that's the case, I'm confused about the purpose of a UDF in these templates, as it seems to only allow for adding or removing columns.

Could anyone provide some insight into this error? I'm also curious to know if it's possible to perform this kind of filtering using a dataflow template with a UDF. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

See the code I use below:

```js
 * @param {string} inJson
 * @return {string} outJson
 */
function process(inJson) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(inJson);
    // Only output objects which have a status of "deleted".
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('status') && obj['status'] === "deleted") {
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    }
```

See the error log:

Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)

com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2514)

com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.JavascriptDocumentTransformer$TransformDocumentViaJavascript$1.processElement(JavascriptDocumentTransformer.java:237)

com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.transforms.JavascriptDocumentTransformer$TransformDocumentViaJavascript$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:803)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1792)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$3000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2218)

org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn.processElement(Read.java:321)

org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$BoundedSourceAsSDFWrapperFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1100)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:143)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:659)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:654)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:348)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:275)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:213)

org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver.java:158)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:537)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)

org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)

java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)

java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbUtils.getTableSchema(MongoDbUtils.java:119)

com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.mongodb.templates.MongoDbToBigQuery$1.process(MongoDbToBigQuery.java:146)

Comment: I'd consider two more guards in your code.  The first is checking whether or not obj is set to a value following a JSON.parse(inJson).  Maybe its value is null.  Second, in your logic, you guard that the obj.status === "deleted" ... but what if it is not.  What is your default return?  I don't see you returning anything if the expression is false.

Comment: Thank you @Kolban. So that is what I am trying to achieve, I do not want to transfer that document or row if the status is not deleted. I have tried setting it to return null when the condition is not met and that fails as well with the same error. And for the first; do you mean like to add a log that checks if object is correctly parsed?

Comment: If the User Option is selected as NONE, you see this error. It should be selected as FLATTEN.